# Field Maps with ArduSimple GNSS

Tags: gps, land-survey, arcgis-field-maps, rtkgps+

I was able to use ArduSimple RTK GNSS normally with Esri Collector. Now with Field Maps it behaves strange. I have an NTRIP subscription and my integration app [Lefebure NTRIP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lefebure.ntripclient&hl=en&gl=US) works great. It can supply positions to other apps via mock location. The values are reported correctly in all apps. Even other Esri apps like Survey123 and Quick Capture work fine.

In Esri Field Maps it reports wrong accuracy. The horizontal accuracy is stuck on 3.9m and vertical on 50cm! Any suggestions to make it work correctly?

My phone is Android 12.

Comment: What did ESRI Support suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and solve it with technical support of Esri distributor.
The oldest version of Collector (18.0.3) works correct. With Lefebure NTRIP is accuracy 1 cm.
And I want to confirm Esri Survey123 and QuickCapture work fine. So problem is somewhere inside Field Maps. I tested connection using cable (https://www.ardusimple.com/mock-location-with-usb-otg/) and it works. Although it’s so uncomfortable, it works!
The horizontal accuracy on 3,9m is solved in latest version Field Maps 22.4.0.
But I have different problem in Field Maps connected using Bluetooth with ArduSimple RTK GNSS. I have Lefebure NTRIP app too. This app is source for mock location. But when I use integrate location service in Field Maps, blue point with my position is still changing. Few seconds I have accuracy 1 cm, but during the second is my accuracy 10 m a blue point is somewhere. Then for few second is ok again, but It happened round and round.